# Python unit testing for methods working on complex objects

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have inherited a relatively large (~30.000 lines) Python-based project (running on a CAD system for architects) with some messy methods that I have to bugfix at first and go on with the development. These methods place, say, bricks (or stuff like that), into a wall. So most of the code does 3D calculations on coords, vectors, etc.

There are no unit tests for the project currently (and I'm a complete noob for unit testing, I'm a brick-and-mortar architect).  Because of the complexity of the functions I have decided to support my work with unit testing, the question is that how can I do it most effectively. Examples I have seen before are much website-based, working mostly on text docs.

The incoming parameters are very complex and large objects, and I use only few of the stored data. Obviously I have to make templates out of it.

There are two possible ways:

1. To save a real word data as a Python pickle and later use this as a template, and save it to disk.
2. To set up objects dynamically. Note that used objects' `__init__()` methods are mostly like this:

```
class FirstClass:
    def __init__(): 
      self.x = 0
      self.y = 0
      self.fc = self.FirstClass()

class SecondClass:
    def __init__():
        self.blabla = 0
```

and so on, there are no complicated calculations. Obviously I can put my custom data by overwriting the initialized instance variables like this:

```
objects.in_the_test_used_data = some_numbers
```

My question is which is the better method for templates, or whether there is a better approach for this et.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches are valid, but with a small changes.

For the first approach, you can pickle everything, but it might be easier to maintain a json/xml/etc file, if you can do that you can change the data in the future, it will be an easy change, over re-pickling.

For the second approach, you can define your own test-classes/test-instances, but the real solution would be to use a **factory library**, I personally love [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It let you define factories for your classes, and help you generate instances easily.

for instance:

```
class AccountFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = objects.Account

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'john%s' % n)
    email = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: '%s@example.org' % o.username)
    date_joined = factory.LazyFunction(datetime.datetime.now)
```

Will let you call `AccountFactory()` and get an `Account` object.

Personally, I prefer the second method, it let you be flexible about your data, make changes, easy to read and has a great API. You will also avoid using large files that has to be committed to your version control and won't really be readable.

Comment: Since the object given to the tested function may contain references that can contain infinite referencing (object A -> object B -> object A), I also prefer the second option.The factory stuff is all new to me, thx for sharing the idea.

Comment: I won't go into details because this is too board, but check out `SubFactory`. You can also init a factory with an instance: `AccountFactory(profile=ProfileFactory(country=(CountryFactory())))`